# Remove non-empty option from select box with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form which has 3 email addresses, and 3 corresponding dropdowns, for email type.

The types are 'Preferred', 'Home', 'Work' and 'Other'

Only one email address can be preferred, so I want to remove that option from the other 2 select boxes when it is selected, and add it back if it is deselected.

I am using Angular.

Is there a way to do this?  I'm guessing a filter of some sort could do it, but I'm pretty new to Angular and have never done anything like this before.

Looking for as close to a "pure" Angular solution as I can get.

I don't have control over how the data is stored, so please refrain from suggesting an alternate scheme.  I also have to build the UI to spec, so I can't add a preferred checkbox - which to me makes WAY more sense, but there it is- or anything like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a filter for each select:

```
<select ng-model='first' ng-options='email as email for email in emails | filter:filterFirst'></select>
<select ng-model='second' ng-options='email as email for email in emails | filter: filterSecond'></select>
<select ng-model='third' ng-options='email as email for email in emails | filter: filterThird'></select>
```

Filters:

```
 $scope.filterFirst = function(value){
   return isPreferred(value, $scope.second, $scope.third);
 }

 $scope.filterSecond = function(value){
   return isPreferred(value, $scope.first, $scope.third);
 }

 $scope.filterThird = function(value){
   return isPreferred(value, $scope.second, $scope.first);
 }

 function isPreferred(target, other1, other2){
   var preferred = "Preferred";
   if(target !== preferred) return true;
   if(other1 ===preferred) return false;
   if(other2 === preferred) return false;
   return true;
 }
```

**Update**
Changed so only the "Preferred" options is excluded.

example http://plnkr.co/edit/RJuMMosFRQslsk0iifI7?p=preview

Comment: This is SOOOOO close to what I need, and what I had arrived at halfway on my own.  How would I modify that so it only responds to 'preferred' tho.  Like any of the other options can be selected more than once.  Preferred is the only one with the restriction of being singular.

Comment: Also close.  That strips all options if Preferred is selected.  If box 1 is Preferred, 2 and 3 should have Home, Work, Other.  If NO box is preferred, all 3 should have Preferred, Home, Work, Other.

Comment: Are you looking at the Plunker? If so I don't think I saved it before. Otherwise it seems to do that?

Comment: Oh yeah.  It wasn't doing that before but is now.  Awesomesauce.  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a software UI designer that was forced into web work. It's a difficult change for them, and it results in very poor specs like what you have to deal with. Please accept my condolences. That being said, let's try to solve this.

You'll need a way to set/reset the values of the dropdowns:

```
$scope.resetEmailTypes = function(){
    var EmailTypes = ['Home', 'Work', 'Other', 'Preferred'];
    $scope.emailType1 = angular.copy(EmailTypes);
    $scope.emailType2 = angular.copy(EmailTypes);
    $scope.emailType3 = angular.copy(EmailTypes);
};
```

On each select tag, attach an ng-change event calling a function similar to this:

```
$scope.setPreferred = function(emailID){
    switch(emailID){
        case 1:
            if($scope.selectedEmailType1 === 'Preferred'){
                $scope.emailType2.pop();
                $scope.emailType3.pop();
            } else {
                $scope.resetEmailTypes();
            }
        case 2:
            if($scope.selectedEmailType2 === 'Preferred'){
                $scope.emailType1.pop();
                $scope.emailType3.pop();
            } else {
                $scope.resetEmailTypes();
            }
        default:
            if($scope.selectedEmailType3 === 'Preferred'){
                $scope.emailType1.pop();
                $scope.emailType2.pop();
            } else {
                $scope.resetEmailTypes();
            }
    }
};
```

Data binding should take care of the rest.

Comment: yeah I wondered about ng-change.  Hadn't tried anything like this yet.  If the filter solution I am currently pursuing falls down, This is my next option.  

I think our designer was more limited to how the data is stored than anything else.  The database side does NOTHING to ensure only one email address is preferred.  It relies completely on the client.  To the DB, preferred is just another type like home, work, etc.  Not sure why they didn't figure it might be useful to have Home is preferred, or Work is preferred - a flag.  But hey - nothing I can do about it except deal.